# Qt: Problemas con QPSQL driver not loaded

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

Este es mi código para el **main.ccp**:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include<QtSql>
#include<QtDebug>
#include<Iostream>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
     db.setHostName("localhost");
     db.setDatabaseName("bd_gdv");
     db.setUserName("postgres");
     db.setPassword("xxxxxxxx");

    if (db.open())
    {
     qDebug() <<"DB Opened";
     db.close();
     }
    else
    {
      qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
     }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Este código me da el siguiente error, he buscado información pero no me queda claro como es que se cargan los drivers

> QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
>
> QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7 "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"

Comment: Viste ésto?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507353/qpsql-driver-not-loaded-qt dice que deberias colocar la ruta del driver en la variable path del sistema.

Comment: Hola! Si, Gracias! Ya habia visto algo parecido...soy principiante y no se como realizar esa operacion de "colocar la ruta del driver en la variable path del sistema." les agradeceria la ayuda con eso please!!

Comment: Ok, mira https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm ahora, seguro que ya instalaste el Qt??, https://www.qt.io/download yo verificaría primero la instalación de QT, eso lo estas haciendo con algun IDE?, que plataforma que base de datos?. Saludos.

Comment: si perfecto! gracias por el primer link, Estoy trabajando con el Qt 5.9 y como SGBD empleo pgAdminIII de PostgreSQL, gracias! voy a echarle un ojo a lo del path a ver si funciona! Saludos zerocool!